# Changing the Date Format

Tags: t-sql

How do I convert Nov 28 2012  3:56PM into yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS. I have a column with incorrectly formatted dates and I need to change the format.

Comment: Date values don't have formats - a format is specified when they are _displayed_.  Where are you seeing the dates in this format?

Comment: What is the data type of the column storing your dates?

Comment: A duplicate of your own question.

Comment: @Blam yet again your being unhelpful its seems you like making silly comments rather than being helpful. The reason I posted a similar question was because I needed an answer which can I can use.

Answer (score 0):

```
CONVERT (datetime, 'Nov 28 2012 3:56PM', 120)
```

That should work, more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want convert a DATE to **VARCHAR**, this query maybe will be useful:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CAST('Nov 27 2012 3:56PM' AS DATETIME),120)
```

In your case, for example, if you field date is **FIELD** then your query will be:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),FIELD,120)
```

You can try this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5583).

**120** is a DateStyle for **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)**

Note: the size of VARCHAR it depends on the format you have chosen.

Comment: The Data Type is nvarchar(19) and I need to format the Dates into 120 and keep it nvarchar(19). I need to change the dates within the column. I hope I made sense.

Comment: Don't do that. Store dates as date types, not varchars.

Comment: @KaisMalique then uses the query I posted, or you need **update** this field with the 120 format?. Why do you use **varchar** for store dates?

Comment: I used the SSIS package to cleanse the data and it defaulted to nvarchar(19) so I'm stuck with it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @KaisMalique Would you fix these records?, in that case, then try this (assuming that your field called for example "date_field"): **UPDATE table SET table.date_field = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),CAST(table.date_field AS DATETIME),120)**